Changing the encryption key
Can anyone who has already changed the encryption key in Magento 2.4.6 via the admin panel help me with this question?
I need to change Magento's encryption key, but I'm afraid that the data encrypted by the old key will be lost.
I made the change in a local environment and noticed a strange behavior in the env.php file, instead of replacing the old key it concatenated the old key with the new one.
Does anyone know if this is standard behavior?


TL; DR
You can't remove your old key, just add in the new key, and then the re-encrypting of data is up to each individual instance's basis (3rd party modules and what not make it impossible to address generally)
There's significant impact to changing the encryption key, and a lot of discussion is going on in the Magento Developer slack #security channel
A module has been built specifically to address the re-encryption piece in Magento. All credit to Luke (and his team)!
There's even a blog post to explain why.
https://www.gene.co.uk/fix-the-critical-adobe-magento-security-vulnerability-with-our-latest-module/
I hope this helps!

The module includes this statement "This module does not conflict with the new hotfix released by Adobe. Both this module and that hotfix improve security in the same way, by making SecretBasedJwksFactory use the most recent key. This module also provides additional tooling and improvements, please read below." If the old key has been compromised can it still be used for malicious API access on a patched system with a rotated encryption key?

So, when you add a new encryption key through the admin panel, Magento will add it to the env.php, and then try re-encrypt all values in the database with the new key. If for whatever reason, some values might fail to re-encrypt, Magento keeps the old key, to make it possible to decrypt old keys, this is not weird and it's quite common across industry, you don't just replace the key, you add to the list. Why Magento decided to make the list a string separated by a newline character is beyond me, could be some technical debt from the past.
If you access the database directly, navigate to core_config_data and find any value that you know is encrypted, you can find that these values start with a number. If you only have one encryption key, then this value will always start with 0:, if you've added a new encryption key, then it might start with 1:, this value tells magento which encryption key to use to decrypt this value, so the order in which these keys appear in the env.php also matters.
Lastly, you can just add a new key to the env.php manually, the only caveat is that Magento won't automatically re-encrypt all your data with the new key, but it will use it each time you save a new value. Might be a solution if you are worried about Magento screwing something up during re-encryption process.

In terms of the cosmic sting attack where an attacker already has the old encrpytion key, can this still be used for malicious purposes?

An encryption key secures passwords and other sensitive data in Magento 2. You can let Magento 2 generate this key automatically or create one manually. The encryption key can be modified using the encryption key tool in the Magento 2 Admin Dashboard. For enhanced security, it's recommended to update the encryption key regularly.
Step 1: Log in to your Magento 2 Admin Panel.
Step 2: In the sidebar menu, go to System > Other Settings > Manage Encryption Key.
Step 3: Configure the following settings:

Set Auto-generate Key to Yes to generate a new key.
Set Auto-generate Key to No to use a custom key, then enter your desired key in the New Key field.

Step 4: Now click on the Change Encryption Key button.

I did exactly that. However, I found it strange that instead of replacing the old key with the new one, it actually concatenated the two keys, as shown in the image attached to the question.

Yes, this is because the keys need to be loaded to verify the old passwords that were using the previous key. For more details, please refer to the "function __construct" in vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php.

@GrazittiDev Would highly appreciate if you could elaborate this process further, I believe currently a lot of Magento developers would be interested in this process.

@FaHu Sure actually magento stores both previous and new encryption keys to ensure seamless validation of encrypted data. This means that even if a new key is added, the system can still validate data encrypted with an old key. This process happens automatically, so users are not affected by key updates or changes.
